# Force GCC to flatten and optimize one function?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, inline

I am trying to make GCC inline all calls in one specific function, and optimize it regardless of global optimization settings. The `flatten` attribute seems to do what I want, but only when the whole source file is compiled with the same -O setting. When specifying both `__attribute__((flatten, optimize("O2")))`, GCC apparently ignores the flatten attribute if the rest of the source file is compiled with any other setting than -O2.

This specific function is an interrupt routine, and I need to make sure that the whole function is contained in one continuous chunk of memory. The only function calls are to `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc()` (which only consists of `rdtsc` and `ret`), and two `std::atomic` operations.

So, as the title says, is there any way to force these calls to be inlined and optimized?

Comment: I don't think so. But why can't you require a global -O setting for this translation unit?

Comment: So, put this function in its own source file and compile it separately.

Comment: @BoPersson, thanks, this seems like a good idea. However, this now turns a `while (!irq.data.my_flag);` into an infinite loop when compiling with -O2 globally, even though `my_flag` is defined as `volatile bool`...

Comment: Just a clarification, how was your `irq` struct defined? Did this behavior had to do with `-O2` or was it a bug when `flatten` was used?

Comment: Oh boy, I don't remember actually. It's only been less than two years but it feels like ages ago. I do know that I eventually settled on turning the whole code segment into non-paged memory, so I didn't have to rely on 'hacks' like these function attributes.